# Form submit button that kills my navbar

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

To do the login / logout of my website, I use a simple button that leads to a modal form who leads to a log action for the login.

For the logout, the best way I found is to use a dummy form who just contains the logout button that leads to the log action.

Everything works but the dummy forms kills my navbar design.[image: bug]

PHP Code :

```html
      <!-- Login -->
      <?php
      if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
          echo '
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalExample" style="margin-left: 10px">Login</button>
        ';
      }
      else {
          echo '

        <form action="actions/log.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Log out" class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin-left: 10px">
        </form>
        ';
      }
      ?>
```

Navbar :

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="90">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Beauty Website</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#othersec">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#versatility">Offers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#lightbox">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#opportunities">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Appointment</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Do you know how i could make it better ?

Comment: Provide the relative CSS please.

Comment: It's the bootstrap one, not a personnal CSS

Comment: looks like there isnt enough room in the navigation bar for your logout button

Comment: There is enough, that's just my screenshot who cropped it. In reallity it doesn't touch the end of the frame

Comment: How does it "kill it"?

Comment: It makes a weird spacing bug like I shown on the screenshot

Comment: You could use a `button` for the logout, like your login button, and have that come up with a modal that confirms log out and the modal has the actual form.

Comment: Post all of the HTML though. Since what "kills" the navbar is the layout of the navbar when you have the form, I want to see the rest of the navbar. It might just need a simple CSS adjustment.

Comment: Yes a second modal would do the trick but it would be a bit useless ...  I added the navbar HTML.

Comment: Ok I fixed it. I just forgot the class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"  in the logout form ...
Thanks for your answer, you shown me the solution I didn't think about :).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help, I just forgot I had a class in my navbar form.

Here is the working PHP:

```
<!-- Login -->
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    echo '
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalExample" style="margin-left: 10px">Login</button>
  ';
}
else {
    echo '

  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="actions/log.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Log out" class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin-left: 10px">
  </form>
  ';
}
?>
```